# Regular expression grouping with multiple condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Concept

```
Example: 0232699980132
0 232 699980132
0 - segment 1
232 - segment 2  (length = 3)
699980132 - segment 3 (length = 9)
Length of segment 2 and 3 should be 12 or 13
```

Th example has 3 segments, first segment can be 0 or 24 or 0024.
Second segment is 232 or its can 123 or 3434. Third segment can be any number but combination of 2nd and 3rd segment should be 12 or 13.

I tried

```
 /[?:0|24|0024]{1,3}[232|123|3434]{3,4}[0-9]{9}$/
```

Problem: It is working if I fix 3rd segment to min 9 but I have to limit 2nd and 3rd segment to 12 or 13.

I also tried  to make groups but it is messing all

```
/[?:0|24|0024]{1,3}([232|123|3434]{3,4}[0-9])(?=.{14}$)$/
```

Please advise.

https://jsfiddle.net/ohz7nnz7/

Comment: Try grouping constructs, `(...)`, instead of character classes, `[...]`. See [`^(0|24|0024)(232|123|3434)([0-9]{9})$`](https://regex101.com/r/JBMh4t/1)

Comment: do u mean, each segment 2 value would be separate construct?

Comment: How to calculate if length of segment 2 and segment 3 is 12 or 13?

Comment: I have added fiddler link. If you see number[5] then it is not working. Because segment 2 is 3 in length and segment 3 is 10 in length . The need is to  get length of segment 2 and 3 and then if it is 12 or 13 in length. Segment 2 + segment 3 should be 12 or 13.

Comment: Ok, try [`var patt = /^(0024|24|0)(232[0-9]{9,10}|123[0-9]{9,10}|3434[0-9]{9})$/;`](https://jsfiddle.net/ohz7nnz7/1/)

Comment: It is only for segment 2. How segment 3 can be handled? Again, the length for segment 2 and 3 should be 12 or 13

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/ohz7nnz7/3/. I do not see any alternative to use only 1 regex here since JS regex does not support lookbehinds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using 2 different patterns, one for testing and another for extracting.

```
var patt_test = /^(0024|24|0)(232[0-9]{9,10}|123[0-9]{9,10}|3434[0-9]{9})$/;
```

This one will make sure we only match qualifying strings.  Details:

- `^` -start of string
- `(0024|24|0)` - Group 1 (not a character class as in your question!) matching `0024`, `24` or `0` (may be shortened as `((?:00)?24|0)`)
- `(232[0-9]{9,10}|123[0-9]{9,10}|3434[0-9]{9})`  - Group 2 capturing:

  - `232[0-9]{9,10}` - `232` number and then 9 or 10 digits
  - `123[0-9]{9,10}` - `123` number and then 9 or 10 digits
  - `3434[0-9]{9}` - `3434` number and then 9 digits
- `$` - end of string.

Once the string is validated this way, we may proceed to extract the 3 parts with:

```
var patt_extract = /^(0024|24|0)(232|123|3434)(\d{9,10})$/;
```

Details:

- `^(0024|24|0)` - `0024`, `24`, or `0` at the start of string
- `(232|123|3434)` - Group 2 capturing `232`, `123` or `3434` *literal char sequences*
- `(\d{9,10})` - Group 3: any 9 to 10 digits
- `$` - end of string

```js
var number = [];
number[0] = "0232699980132"; // this should be true as starts with 0
number[1] = "008973343430145"; // false
number[2] = "24232667870167"; // true
number[3] = "0024232656880187"; // true
number[4] = "024232623432190"; // this should be false because middle segment 24 is not allowed
number[5] = "02326568801878"; // this should be true

console.clear();
var patt_test = /^(0024|24|0)(232[0-9]{9,10}|123[0-9]{9,10}|3434[0-9]{9})$/;
var patt_extract = /^(0024|24|0)(232|123|3434)(\d{9,10})$/;
var result = false;
for(i=0; i<=(number.length-1); i++) {
 result = patt_test.test(number[i]);
  if (result) { // VALIDATE THE STRING
   var first, second, third;
   var m = patt_extract.exec(number[i]); // EXTRACT PARTS
   if (m) { first = m[1]; second = m[2]; third = m[3]; }
   var str = number[i]+" -- "+result+"--"+number[i].length+"--P1:"+first+"--P2:"+second+"--P3:"+third;
   console.log(str);
  } else {
     console.log(number[i]+" -- "+result+"--"+number[i].length);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
^(?:0024|24|0)(?=(?:232|123)\d{10}$)(?=3434(?:\d{9})$)
```

or

```
^(?:0024|24|0)(?:(?:232|123)\d{10}|3434(?:\d{9}))$
```

Comment: Is there anyway to get length of segment 2 and segment 3?